# BASH - RSYNC : How to get sub directories and their files with the parameters --files-from

Tags: bash, rsync

I'm trying to backup my `/home` to a remote server with Rsync. I want to backup some directories and their content but not all of directoeries of my `/home`.

I use the parameters below to my command

```
--files-from=list
```

The problem is only the files and directoies on my `list` are transfered, but not their contents (sub-directories and files).

May I have to use wellcards after each directories on `list` to also transfer their contents ? Or there is an other solution ?

Many thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: `--files-from==FILE` is for including specific files and will not recurse. Use `--include-from==FILE` to do what you need. You will still need to specify `--recursive | -r` on the command line.

Comment: @alvits 

Thank you for your answer. I fear that `--include-from` will be useless until I made a rsync on the whole `/home` at the begining. But you're right !

Have a good day from France :)